# compare 2 csv files uing the merge and compare row by row

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, merge

so I have 2 CSV files in file1 I have list of research groups names. in file2 I have list of the Research full name with location as wall. I want to join these 2 csv file if the have the words matches in them.

in file1.cvs

| research_groups_names |
| --- |
| Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS) |
| CAS |
| U-M |
| UQ |

in file2.cvs

| research_groups_names | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS) | China |
| University of Michigan (U-M) | United States of America (USA) |
| The University of Queensland (UQ) | Australia |

the Output.csv

| f1_research_groups_names | f2_research_groups_names | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chinese Academy of Sciences | Chinese Academy ofSciences(CAS) | China |
| CAS | Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS) | China |
| U-M | University of Michigan (U-M) | United States of America(USA) |
| UQ | The University of Queensland (UQ) | Australia |

```
     import pandas as pd
    df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
    
    df2 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')

    df1 = df1.add_prefix('f1_')
    df2 = df2.add_prefix('f2_')

    
    
    def compare_nae(df):
        if  df1['f1_research_groups_names'] == df2['f2_research_groups_names']:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    
      
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['f1_research_groups_names'],right_on=['f2_research_groups_names'], how="left")

    result.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: so the research_groups_names could and will be present in other dataframe anywhere in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
def fn(row):
    for _, n in df2.iterrows():
        if (
            n["research_groups_names"] == row["research_groups_names"]
            or row["research_groups_names"] in n["research_groups_names"]
        ):
            return n


df1[["f2_research_groups_names", "f2_location"]] = df1.apply(fn, axis=1)
df1 = df1.rename(columns={"research_groups_names": "f1_research_groups_names"})
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
            f1_research_groups_names           f2_research_groups_names                     f2_location
0  Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS)  Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS)                           China
1                                CAS  Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS)                           China
2                                U-M       University of Michigan (U-M)  United States of America (USA)
3                                 UQ  The University of Queensland (UQ)                       Australia
```

---

Note: If in `df1` is name not found in `df2` there will be `None`, `None` in columns `"f2_research_groups_names"` and `"f2_location"`

Comment: I got this error ValueError: Columns must be same length as key ?

Comment: cvs row count for file1.csv 4000 data, and for file2.csv I have about 13,000                ---- I tried add this but it didn't work df1[["f2_research_groups_names", "f2_location"]].str.split(' - ', expand=True, n=1) = df1.apply(fn, axis=1)